# Test multiple properties using _.every

Tags: angularjs, for-loop, lodash, continue

I was asked to change some code using lodash's `_.every`:

```
//for every item in collection, check if "someProp" is true, 
//but only if "someProp2" isn't "-1". If "someProp" is true for 
//every item in collection, return true.

$scope.areAllTrue = function() {
    for(var i=0; i<$scope.collection.length; i++){
        if($scope.collection[i].someProp2 === -1) {
            continue;
        }
        if(!$scope.collection[i].someProp) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
};
```

So following the lodash [example](http://devdocs.io/lodash/index#every) of:

```
_.every(users, 'active', false);
```

We get:

```
$scope.areAllTrue = function() {
    return _.every($scope.collection, 'someProp', true)
};
```

This handles the "For every item in the collection, check if someProp is true, if all are true, return true." But can I do the "continue" check here somehow?

Edit: Can I use two predicates with "_.every" somehow? Like `if someProp1 === true || someProp2 === -1` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[_.every()](https://lodash.com/docs#every) can use a predicate function:

```
_.every(users, function(user) {
    return user.someProp2 === -1 || user.someProp;
});
```

You can also skip lodash, and use [Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```
users.every(function(user) {
    return user.someProp2 === -1 || user.someProp;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess that was way simpler than I made it out to be. Edit: Didn't know about every - cool. I hate using libraries when same thing can be done without.

Comment: Welcome, and I'm taking from you the "/min comment length" :)